# Como converter um tipo de atributo string para o tipo IFormFile no C# ASPNET Core?

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho uma classe `Product`, na qual um de seus atributos é a propriedade string abaixo:

```cs
public string ImageUrl{get; set;}
```

Em um dos meus *controllers* para realizar *update* de registro, preciso
atribuir o valor dessa propriedade em uma variável do tipo `IFormFile`. Ex.:

```cs
IFormFile img = product.ImageUrl;
```

Qual a melhor maneira de realizar essa atribuição convertendo o valor de `product.ImageUrl` em `IFormFile` para receber na variavel `img`?

```cs
 public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {

            if (id == null || _context.Products == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var product = await _context.Products.FindAsync(id);

            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }


            var modelProduct = new ProductViewModel
            {
                ProductId = product.ProductId,
                ProductDescription = product.ProductDescription,
                ProductName = product.ProductName,
                ProductPrice = product.ProductPrice,
                Category = product.Category,
                CategoryId = product.CategoryId,
                IsActive = product.IsActive,
                IsFeatured = product.IsFeatured,
                Quantity = product.Quantity,
                ImageUrl = product.ImageUrl,
                ImageThumbnailUrl = product.ImageThumbnailUrl,
            };

            ViewData["CategoryId"] = new SelectList(_context.Categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName", product.CategoryId);
            return View(product);
        }
```

No código acima, as propriedade ImageUrl e ImageUrlThumbanail, são propriedades do tipo IFormFile da classe ProductsViewModel.
Essas propriedades estão sendo atribuidas com os valores das propriedade ImageUrl e ImageUrlThumbnail da classe Products formada atraveés de consulta ao banco de dados e está no formato string.
Preciso pegar esse valor vindo do banco do dados que está em string e atribuir nas propriedades IFormFile para exibir os dados nos inputs do front-end.
Qual seria a melhor maneira de realizar esse procedimento.

Comment: [IFormFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-6.0) é uma interface que não é um tipo concreto. Declarar uma interface como tipo dum identificador é estabelecer uma restrição para que objetos referenciados pelo identificador implementem obrigatoriamente a tal interface. No seu caso `img` apenas pode guardar referencias a objetos que implemente `IFormFile`. Instancie a classe [FormFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.formfile?view=aspnetcore-6.0) de acordo suas necessidades.

Comment: Olá @AugustoVasques

Estou criando no controlador  AdminProductsController, um metodo para editar um registro já gravado no banco de dados. 
Quando realizo o carregamento da pagina de edição do registros, preciso trazer as propriedades que estão gravadas no banco de dados diretamente nos inputs(html).0
No caso tenho a View model ProductsView model que precisa receber um valor IFormFile, porém o objeto atribuido a propriedade veio em String, que nada mais é que o nome da imagem.  
Como preencher um input html, no qual seu Id está vinculado a uma propriedade IFormFile?

Comment: !Olhe o constructor da classe [`FormFile`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.formfile.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-formfile-ctor(system-io-stream-system-int64-system-int64-system-string-system-string)), a partir da url/path da imagem você pode obter todas as informações para instanciar uma classe `FormFile`.

Comment: Quando você guarda na sua base a url da imagem e o arquivo no seu diretório e deseja mostrar essa imagem na sua `View`, não é necessário nem é usual e ao meu entender errado converter uma imagem em FormFile, é só mostrar essa imagem em um componente `<img/>`. Ou seja, você está indo pelo caminho que não vai levar a lugar nenhum, porque, não é assim que se faz. Quando você grava a imagem, você recebe os dados via `POST` armazena a foto e guarda o endereço ou contrário não é válido.